# Strange approximation to $\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, radicals, irrational-numbers, pi

Let
$$\alpha = \sqrt{2\sin^2 1+\sqrt{2\sin^2 2 + \sqrt{2\sin^2 3 + \cdots}}} =\sqrt{3.1415...}$$
Prove that $\alpha^2 \neq \pi$. It is a remarkable approximation though.

Comment: Is it till infinity?

Comment: $\sin^2 1$, that's $1$ radian?

Comment: @GEdgar: yes, radians.

Comment: @Zenix: the nested radicals go indefinitely, but only the first 4 digits match those of $\pi$.

Comment: A cool find, maybe it was just random just as with $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\approx \pi$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy numerically.  It is well known that $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}=2$$ so the tail in the nested radical is always less than $2$.  We find that $$\alpha < \sqrt{2\sin^2 1+\sqrt{2\sin^2 2 + \sqrt{2\sin^2 3 + \cdots +\sqrt{2\sin^2 13+2}}}}\approx 1.7724371077589929$$ so that $$\alpha^2 < 3.1415333009610635 < \pi$$

Here's my python script:

```
from math import sqrt, sin

def f(n):
    answer = 2+sqrt(2*sin(n)**2)
    for k in range(n-1,0,-1):
        answer = sqrt(2*(sin(k)**2)+answer)
    return answer

alpha = f(13)
print(alpha, alpha**2)
```

This prints

```
1.7724371077589929 3.1415333009610635
```

Comment: That doesn't look $< \pi$ to me...?

Comment: However, changing 7 into 13 in your script gives $\alpha^2 < \pi$ as desired.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Wow.  I must be getting cross-eyed.  Thanks